# Filling gaps in rows once namaz has commenced

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Can someone please shed some light on what should be done if  space becomes free in front of you once namaaz has commenced.
I have noticed ,especially in tarawee prayer gaps/space in the front rows become available. These are filled slowly. Thus people in rows further back commence their namaaz only for a space infront to become free.

What is the ruling on this. I have heard various opinions on this. Can someone tell me what you should do if the space becomes free on

a) ones right or left (how one closes the gap)

b) directly in front of you

c) diagonally in front of you(can you cut across somone to your right or left to fill the row in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

*Part of this straightening is completing the rows and connecting them, and not leaving gaps between worshippers. Abu Dawood (666) narrated from ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Straighten the rows, stand shoulder to shoulder and fill the gaps; **be gentle with their hands of your brothers**, and do not leave gaps for the Shaytaan. Whoever connects a row, Allah will connect him (with His mercy), and whoever breaks a row, Allah will cut him off (from His mercy).”*

By that part of the sentence I conclude the following:

Just talk to your brother next of you (from your left or from your right) if you he wants to go forward, otherwise you go. It's as easy as that. You shouldn't be angry if someone takes the place in front of you even if he stands two places next to you and didn't discuss it.

Remember you're there with the same goal, namely praying before Allah.

So I hope this suffices as an answer to your question.

Source:

https://islamqa.info/en/158560

Comment: Downvoter can you undo your action? I've added a source.

Answer (score 0):

Assalaamu a'laykum wa ragmatullahie wabarakaatu!

To the best of my knowledge, as I'm not learned, if Salaah commenced ALREADY and there's a gap in between you and the person next to you,  you should slide your feet to get closer to the next person to close the gap without lifting your feet from the ground. That's as far as I know.

Jazaka Allah khayr(an)!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible things you could do.Allah is watching.You could fill up the space.There can be consequences or good things depending on the will of allah.Allah keeps rewards on every action or punishes or does according to his will.He might not be easy to comprehend.
On one end,other people might not like it.On another end, it becomes a good deed.It can also become a bad deed if other people are harmed by empty gaps being filled up and it can also not be smart to fill gaps especially when prayers have commenced.
You be the judge and do what you think is right.